# How can I display 2 models In 1 view?

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

So I have a Django app where I want the user to be able to input a question and then like 3 choices for another user to guess

Models.py

```
from django.conf import settings 
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse



class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(), 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
    
    def check_answer(self, choice):
        return self.choice_set.filter(id=choice.id, is_answer=True).exists()

    def get_answers(self):
        return self.choice_set.filter(is_answer=True)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article_detail', args=[str(self.id)])

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='choices', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    is_answer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article_list')
```

and then my views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import (
    LoginRequiredMixin,
    UserPassesTestMixin
)
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView, DeleteView, CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import Question
from .forms import QuestionAddForm, EditQuestionForm, ChoiceAddForm
 
 
class QuestionListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'article_list.html'

class QuestionDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'article_detail.html'

class QuestionUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Question
    fields = ('question', 'body') 
    template_name = 'article_edit.html'

    def test_func(self):
        obj = self.get_object()
        return obj.author == self.request.user

class QuestionDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'article_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('article_list')

    def test_func(self):
        obj = self.get_object()
        return obj.author == self.request.user

class QuestionCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Question
    template_name = "article_new.html"
    fields = ('question', 'body')

    def form_valid(self, form):       
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

and finally the page where I add a new question

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}


    <h1>New quiz</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.as_p }}
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success ml-2" type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

How could I achieve my goal of allowing a user to add a question with 3 choices using the code I already have

Comment: Make two forms and one submit for them ?

Comment: How do I do that

Comment: You can basically make a form tag and insert both forms in it using `{{ form1 }}` and `{{ form2 }}` then check that the 2 forms are valid or not in views.